# How to install Docker on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, docker

I've installed Ubuntu 17.04 (VirtualBox). But since I have Ubuntu 17.04, it seems like docker is not yet available for Ubuntu 17.04. Is there any workaround to install Docker on Ubuntu 17.04?

**This is my commande line history:**

```
 2  curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.10.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&   chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&   sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
 3  docker-machine version
 4  docker pull ubuntu:latest
 5  sudo apt-get update
 6  sudo apt-get install     linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)     linux-image-extra-virtual
 7  sudo apt-get install     apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     curl     software-properties-common
 8  sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
 9  sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
10  lsb_release -cs
11  sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"
12  sudo apt-get update
13  sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y
```

**This is the actual error:**

```
user@user-vm:~$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease       
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Hit:4 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease                 
Ign:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease                      
Ign:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty Release
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                   
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                      
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages                                                                                                                             
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages                                                                                                                           
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US                                                                                                                        
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en                                                                                                                          
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                     
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                   
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                      
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages                                                                                                                             
Ign:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages                                                                                                                           
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US                                                                                                                        
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en                                                                                                                          
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                     
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                   
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                      
Ign:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all Packages                                                                                                                             
Err:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 Packages                                                                                                                           
404  Not Found
Ign:9 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en_US                                                                                                                        
Ign:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable Translation-en                                                                                                                          
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable all DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                     
Ign:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                                                                                   
Ign:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty/stable DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                                                                                      
Fetched 89.2 kB in 12s (7'258 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/zesty/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[tutorial I was following](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

Comment: as of mid-2017, docker-ce 17.06 is available for Ubuntu 17.04 (it was released June 2017, and hence is version 17.06) -- just follow steps here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/  (and get docker-compose from `pip` (eg, `sudo -H pip3 install docker-compose`) and  _not_ from ubuntu repos, which are out-of-date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no official support of docker in Ubuntu 17.04 yet. An alternative is to download and install the binary of docker from https://github.com/moby/moby/releases.

For example if you want to install docker version 17.04.0-ce from binary, follow these steps:

```
$ wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz
$ tar xzvf docker-17.04.0-ce.tgz
$ cd docker
```

This `docker` directory contains all the binaries. You need to add this directory to your [`PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path).
You will need to manually start `dockerd` first.
[This page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/#install-static-binaries) contains more details about how to install and run docker from a binary.

Comment: You can also just use the xenial repository, see my answer

Comment: Be aware that the get.docker.com packages are outdated, and that the `.tgz` archives contain statically linked binaries, which may not be what you want. Docker now has packages available for Ubuntu zesty; see https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/. The installation script at https://get.docker.com is still up to date though, so running that will install the correct packages

Answer (score 60):

Docker hasn't setup a repository for the latest ubuntu, but that's an easy fix because their release for ubuntu 16 is compatible. For the time being, just edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and on the line:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
```

Replace `zesty` by `xenial`. Run `sudo apt-get update` and you can proceed with `sudo apt-get install docker-ce`

Comment: If you are adding this directly like I was you will want the PGP key for this repo - `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8`

Comment: @bluehallu: saw your edit, but I can't get it to work with today's repo. apt-get says there is no installation candidate for docker-ce

Comment: @ThiagoArrais removed edit, I probably did something wrong when testing

Comment: works great if you add key server as @timelf123 mentioned

Comment: This answer is now out of date, but it didn't work for me, probably due to version mismatches (esp. docker-compose). But it's a moot point now that docker.com (_not_ the ubuntu repos) has a docker-ce release 17.06 for Ubuntu 17.04. (These versions are a little confusing: docker-ce released in June of 2017 is v17.06).   If installing docker-ce from docker.com, then docker-compose will have to be installed from docker-compose's git release, or via `sudo -H pip install docker-compose`, and not from ubuntu repos, which are now useless for docker related stuff (as of mid-2017).

Answer (score 17):

Just a quick note: Currently to install docker-ce on ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) you need to be on the edge channel: see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32423#issuecomment-300164496

Therefore you need to add `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty edge` to your sources.

Comment: the docker-ce instructions have finally been updated to be useful https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/  one should add the `stable` repo, either way, and add `edge` if necessary (stable now includes a release for ubuntu 17.04 zesty)

Answer (score 14):

The information in this thready is outdated and can result in malfunctioning docker installation; ubuntu zesty is now supported, and packages are available; see the installation manual: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

## Uninstall old versions

Older versions of Docker were called `docker` or `docker-engine`. If these are installed, uninstall them:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
```

## Automated Installation

If you want all the installation steps to be done "automatically", you can also use the installation script at https://get.docker.com/

## Install Using the Repository

Update the apt package index:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS:

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
```

Add Docker’s official GPG key:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Verify that the key fingerprint is `9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88.`

```
$ sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

pub   4096R/0EBFCD88 2017-02-22
      Key fingerprint = 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
uid                  Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   4096R/F273FCD8 2017-02-22
```

Use the following command to set up the stable repository (for the `amd64` architecture):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

INSTALL DOCKER CE

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

Thanks Sebastiaan van Stijn for helping me with this.

Comment: OK, I have updated the post to include full details of the installation procedure.

Comment: For 17.10, temporarily: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/141

Comment: Worked for me using 17.10 while the https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ didn't

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to make it work. Here's the solution that works for me:

1. Use the solution proposed by Ravexina:

   `sudo apt install docker.io`
2. Then use this :

   `sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker`
3. Finally, reboot my system

Voilà ... it works perfect.

Comment: This will install the rather old version (currently 1.12.6-0ubuntu4) from the standard Ubuntu repository. If you follow the solution by @Georgi-Goranov, you will get the latest version (currently 17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-zesty).

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D  
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-zesty testing'    
apt-get update    
apt-cache policy docker-engine    
apt-get install docker-engine
```

Comment: This will install docker-engine, not docker-ce

Comment: it is working for me

Answer (score 2):

Just use following

`curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
..
..
..
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

Source: https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.05.0-ce

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 17.04 the deb install from the official repo worked just fine (17.05)

https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.05.0-ce

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# file: src/bash/aspark-starter/install-docker-on-ubuntu-17.04.sh
# Purpose: 
# to automate the installation of docker-ce on Ubuntu 17.04 zesty
# 
# courtesy of https://askubuntu.com/a/944174/251228
set -eu -o pipefail # fail on error , debug all lines

# run as root
[ "$USER" = "root" ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"

echo "=== $BASH_SOURCE on $(hostname -f) at $(date)" >&2

err_msg="\n\nthis script is only for Ubuntu 17.04 zesty, BUT you have: \n"$(lsb_release -a)
test $(lsb_release -cs) != "zesty" && echo -e "$err_msg"
test $(lsb_release -cs) != "zesty" && exit 1

echo Install Using the Repository
echo Update the apt package index:


apt-get update

echo Install packages to allow apt to use a repository over HTTPS:

apt-get install -y \
     apt-transport-https \
     ca-certificates \
     curl \
     software-properties-common


echo Add Dockerâ€™s official GPG key:
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -


echo Verify that the key fingerprint is 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88.
apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

echo << EOF_STDOUT
# the output should look like : 
# 
# pub   4096R/0EBFCD88 2017-02-22
# Key fingerprint = 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A  E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
# uid                  Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
# sub   4096R/F273FCD8 2017-02-22

EOF_STDOUT


echo Use the following command to set up the stable repository for the amd64 architecture
# src: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181538/37428
# tested only for amd64
arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)
add-apt-repository \
    "deb [arch=""$arch""] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    $(lsb_release -cs) \
    stable"

echo INSTALL DOCKER CE
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce

echo the docker binary is installed in
which docker

echo DONE !!!
# eof file src/bash/aspark-starter/install-docker-on-ubuntu-17.04.sh
```