# Installing the macbuntu 16.10 theme on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, system-installation, themes, 17.04

I just installed 17.04 and I'd like to install this:
http://www.noobslab.com/2016/11/macbuntu-1610-transformation-pack-for.html

However the repositories don't work.  I think there's a simple trick to adjust the repository to allow installation on Zesty instead of xenial.  For example after installing the icon repository and attempting an install this happens:

```
ole@mkiv:~$ sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v8
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say , you can change the PPA Distribution from `zesty` to `yakkety`

(not `xenial` becuase `xenial` repositories has `macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7` but not `macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v8` version).

For this purpose , please follow this path:

**Software & Updates** > **Other software**

And then select `http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu` and click on **Edit...** button.

Then change to Distribution value from `zesty` to `yakkety`.

So that's must be worked.

```
apt-cache search macbuntu-os
macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v8 - These themes is intended to use with Macbuntu by NoobsLab.com
macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v8 - MacBuntu Themes available on NoobsLab.com PPA
macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v8 - MacBuntu Icons & cursors uploaded on NoobsLab.com PPA
```

Comment: You NEVER EVER use a repository from a different version of Ubuntu. It can break your entire system.

Comment: @ubashu Thanks for your reply. Do you know the better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Let's get looking!

Comment: Just remembered where I had seen this - It's also being done for docker here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909691/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: @ubashu in general I think you are right, but in this case I don't really care if the system breaks, because I can just reinstall.  I'm just experimenting to see if I can get this working.

Comment: OK - I tried it and everything works fine.  I'll post back if something blows up in the future.

Comment: @Ole Then a wise thing to do would be do a backup.

Comment: @ubashu now you tell me!!!  :)

Comment: @Ole did anything blow up?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Ubuntu 18.04, you should use the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-v1804
```